# Any hint for this product of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, products

I have to calculate the modulus of $z$. I've already tried to find a general formula for $\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^{2^n}$, which seems to be $\frac{1}{2^{2^{n-1}}}, \forall \geq3$, using the trigonometric form and de Moivre's formula.

$z=\left[1+\frac{1+i}{2}\right] \left[1+\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^2\right] \left[1+\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^4\right] \cdots \left[1+\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^{2^n}\right]$

How should I keep solving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$z=
\frac {[1-(\frac {1+i}{2})]\left[1+\frac{1+i}{2}\right] \left[1+\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^2\right] \left[1+\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^4\right] \cdots \left[1+\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^{2^n}\right]        }{[1-(\frac {1+i}{2})]}=$$

$$\frac { \left[1-\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^{2^{n+1}}\right]        }{[1-(\frac {1+i}{2})]}$$

We may simplify it with $$(\frac{1+i}{2})^2 = \frac {i}{2}$$

Answer (score -1):

Use $\frac {1+i} 2=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} e^{i\pi/4}$. Since $|e^{i\theta}|=1$ for all real $\theta$ we get  $|\frac {1+i} 2|^{2^{n}}=\frac 1 {2^{2^{n-1}}}$.

Comment: Why is $|\frac {1+i} 2|^{2^{n}}=\frac 1 {2^{n-1}}$ and not $\frac{1}{2^{2^{n-1}}}$

Comment: @EmM1500 That was just a typo. Sorry about that.